# Get top value of rotated image in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

So I create and image and place it in a canvas like this:

```
draw() {
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

    var ox = this.x;
    var oy = this.y;

    this.x += (this.speed * this.mod) * Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * this.angle);
    this.y += (this.speed * this.mod) * Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * this.angle);

    this.detectCollision(ox, oy);

    this.context.save();
    this.context.translate(this.x, this.y);
    this.context.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * this.angle);
    this.context.drawImage(this.car, -(this.car.width / 2), -(this.car.height / 2));
    this.context.restore();
}
```

And now I'm trying to make collision detection, but because I rotate the image it is a bit harder in my opinion.

This is my collision detection:

```
detectCollision(ox, oy) {
    // top-left corner
    // OX/OY are old cords
    if (this.car.getBoundingClientRect().top < 0 || this.car.getBoundingClientRect().left < 0) {
        this.x = ox;
        this.y = oy;
    }
}
```

Then I found this function `getBoundingClientRect()` but it keeps returning 0.
Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: getBoundingClientRect only works on DOM-Elements like <div>, not within the canvas context.

Comment: @niorad ahh okey, thanks for the clarification. I'll just search further for another solution.

Comment: Collision of rotating objects is not straightforward. I'd say start without rotation and then buiild up from there. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript/Collision_detection

Comment: Some more https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/collision-detection-using-the-separating-axis-theorem--gamedev-169